# Angular2, moved local variable from *ngFor to any place in template

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" placeholder="City" [(ngModel)]="pipeCity" />
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Location" [(ngModel)]="pipeLocation" />
      </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let city of arrayCities | filter:pipeCity:'city'
                                                       | filter:pipeLocation:'location'
                                                       let last = last; let i = index; count as pipeCount ">
    <tr>
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{city.city}}</td>
      <td>{{city.location}}</td>
      <span *ngIf="last">Found:{{pipeCount}}</span>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am looking for solution to moved `Found:{{pipeCount}}` above to table

```
Found:{{pipeCount}}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
```

I tried by:
a)
create onTemporary function, which is call from component:

```
onTemporary(count){
return this.temporaryValue=count;
}
```

and in template:

```
Found:{{this.temporaryValue}}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
```

But this is not good solution.

b) 
by `@Directive`. But this is working very similar to a). There is any angular solution to moved local variable to any place in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the pipes for the cities, then you just need to do some data evaluation with `.map` and `.reduce`. For example, you should do something like this in `ngOnInit`:

```js
var cities = [
  {
    name: "metropolis",
    suburbs: [ 
      { name: "sub1", pipes: 1 },
      { name: "sub2", pipes: 2 },
      { name: "sub3", pipes: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "super city",
    suburbs: [ 
      { name: "sub1", pipes: 11 },
      { name: "sub2", pipes: 22 },
      { name: "sub3", pipes: 33 }
    ]
  },
  
];

var sum = (val, total) => val + total;
var totalPipesPerCity = cities.map(city => city.suburbs.map(suburb => suburb.pipes).reduce(sum));
var totalPipesInAllCities = totalPipesPerCity.reduce(sum);

console.log(totalPipesPerCity );
console.log(totalPipesInAllCities );
```

Comment: This total is working fine, I did that by `count as pipeCount`. So I have total number of pipes. I need send that parameter outside the table. The best solution for me, will be, like in the question, above to table.

Comment: @profiler I think you've misunderstood, as this will allow you to do: `Found:{{this.totalPipesInAllCities }}` anywhere within the component (above the table if you please). Also, as per the update, you do this in `ngOnInit`, not in the html template.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is highly recommended not to use a filter pipe and instead do your filtering in code. Then your code can expose a property that the template can use anywhere.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

Here is a piece of that code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
    errorMessage: string;

    filteredProducts: IProduct[];
    products: IProduct[] = [];

    _listFilter: string;
    get listFilter(): string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredProducts = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.products;
    }

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {

    }

    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
              product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProducts()
                .subscribe(products => {
                    this.products = products;
                    this.filteredProducts = this.products;
                },
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
Found:{{filteredProducts?.length}}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
```